# Unable to connect to Google Cloud VM via SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been unable to connect to my VM via SSH since changing persistent disks. I had a VM set up with a Balance Persistent Disk 10gb and wanted to switch to a Standard 30gb. My procedure as been:

1. Create a disk image
2. Shutdown current VM and deleted the bootdisk
3. Loaded the saved disk image and switched to a Standard Persistent Disk

Now I am unable to connect via SSH. In Activity I'm getting this message: `Invalid argument (HTTP 400): Supplied fingerprint does not match current metadata fingerprint.` I've added the custom Metadata `enable-os login: TRUE`. Tech is still trying to figure it out.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Can you connect via the instance's serial port consoel?

Comment: I was never directed to by support. I'm not sure how to.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt with support - they determined the disk image was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Tried on my end changing persistent disk to standard disk and with same metadata you've added and it worked in my end using below steps.

1. Compute Engine
2. Disk
3. Select VM's Disk
4. Create Image
5. Location same with seleted VM
6. Save
7. VM Instance > Select VM > Down > Edit
8. Detached Boot Disk
9. Configure Boot Disk > Custom Images > Select Project > Select Image > Boot disk Type to Standard > Select
10. Make Sure to check **Allow http/https traffic**

Worth to try also below:

1. Recreate image from disk, found some other fingerprint errors due to disk issue and was solve by remounting and fixing fstab key.
2. Generate/Create [SSH Key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/create-ssh-keys?hl=en) and add on VM Instance > edit
3. Guide on [Connecting Linux VM using advance method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#before-you-begin)

Comment: update: thank you both for the recommendations. It ended up being a corrupt disk image. Bah. Oh well!

Comment: @bighelpdiscord, Kindly consider upvoting recomendations/answers if you find it useful.